# Clickhouse kafka engine. How to set the data collection interval from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I need to configure the CH table with the Kafka engine so that the table takes data from Kafka in large chunks, but not constantly, but let's say at intervals of 30 seconds or 1 minute. Is it possible to do this, I did not find a parameter responsible for this interval. I'm new to using Kafka and CH

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `kafka_flush_interval_ms` settings. This setting determines how often ClickHouse flushes data from Kafka to the table.

Increase this setting to a higher value to ensure data is ingested less frequently. For example, for a 1-minute interval, you would set this to 60000 (milliseconds in a minute).

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE kafka_table (...fields...)
ENGINE = Kafka 
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'broker:port',
         kafka_topic_list = 'your_topic',
         kafka_group_name = 'your_group',
         kafka_format = 'YourDataFormat',
         kafka_flush_interval_ms = 60000;  -- Set this to the desired interval in milliseconds
```

This will configure the ClickHouse Kafka table to flush (ingest) the data approximately every 1 minute.